# Small TV furniture (current screen is 55") also fits a much larger 75" screen?

Tags: television

I have a TV furniture, which is very valuable to me because I got it as a gift. The TV furniture has a width of 107cm and currently there is a 55" LG TV on it. I want a bigger TV, but keep the old TV furniture.

[image]

I want to stay with LG TV, because I do not have a Google account (no Android TV), but still want to have apps.

Somewhat surprised I found that on this small TV furniture can also stand a 75" LG TV, ie the base width is not at all larger for some models. In German they say `Standfussbreite`, I hope DeepL translated it correctly.

That surprises me very much. Can my research be correct? I can hardly believe it.

Answer (score 1):

The screen size can be much larger than the stand which supports the screen. As all of the forces are transmitted to the surface by the stand, one needs only to have a surface which will safely support the stand. A smaller surface than the overall screen may permit contact from persons, which could result in the television tipping over, but that's unrelated to the physics of gravity in this circumstance.

Comment: @Sybil You can add a safety brace ([example](https://avfgroup.com/uk/product/ast30-universal-telescopic-tv-safety-bar/) - I have one similar to this) to prevent your TV being knocked off the stand by at least moderate knocks.